# error "Failed to read the default logging configuration" while deploying Google APP Engine app

Tags: java, maven, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

i have updated my google app engine gcloud sdk and now when i am trying to deploy a project this error is coming

```
[INFO] GCLOUD: INFO: Failed to read the default logging configuration
        [INFO] GCLOUD: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\java\config\sdk\logging.properties (The system cannot find the path specified)
        [INFO] GCLOUD:  at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
        [INFO] GCLOUD:  at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
        [INFO] GCLOUD:  at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
        [INFO] GCLOUD:  at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:93)
        [INFO] GCLOUD:  at java.util.logging.LogManager.readConfiguration(LogManager.java:1301)
        [INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.appengine.tools.util.Logging.initializeLogging(Logging.java:38)
        [INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg.main(AppCfg.java:111)
        [INFO] GCLOUD: 
        [INFO] GCLOUD: Reading application configuration data...
        [INFO] GCLOUD: Bad configuration: Schema file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\java\docs\appengine-web.xsd does not exist.
        [INFO] GCLOUD: Please see the logs [C:\Users\kamlesh\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg2029405644917018939.log] for further information.
        [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
        [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
        [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
        [INFO] Total time: 18.148 s
        [INFO] Finished at: 2018-03-22T18:37:06+05:30
        [INFO] Final Memory: 29M/256M
        [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
        [ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.google.cloud.tools:appengine-maven-plugin:1.3.2:deploy (default-cli) on project quizone-apis: Execution default-cli of goal com.google.cloud.tools:appengine-maven-plugin:1.3.2:deploy failed: Non zero exit: 1 -> [Help 1]
        [ERROR] 
        [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
        [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
        [ERROR] 
        [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
        [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException
        Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Does `C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\java\config\sdk\logging.properties` exist on your system?

Comment: I have a few questions to help narrow down the issue.

Does the file “appengine-web.xsd” exist in the in the filesystem?
Does the appcfg2029405644917018939.log file contain any more relevant information on this deployment error?
Does pom.xml file contain the appengine-maven-plugin:1.3.2 [plugin](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/app-maven-plugin/blob/master/README.md#user-content-how-to-use)?

Comment: @Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\java\" does not have any config folder please help sir

Comment: In this case, I suggest you try to reinstall the Cloud SDK for App Engine. Choose the correct environment and programming language [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/downloads).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem.

As @Kenworth commented on your question, I checked and my appengine-maven-plugin was version 1.3.1.

After I updated it to 1.3.2 in my pom.xml that stacktrace doesn't show anymore.